# How to calculate U-spin for baryons

Tags: particle-physics, group-representations, quarks, baryons

I am trying to calculate U-spin for sigma baryons. I don't know why U-spin for $\Sigma^{+}$ and $\Sigma^{-}$ and $\Sigma^{*+}$ is 1/2, but for $\Sigma^{*-}$ is 3/2?

I know that $\Sigma^{+}$ and $\Sigma^{-}$ are octet, and $\Sigma^{*+}$ and $\Sigma^{*-}$ are decuplet, but I don't understand their U-spins.

Comment: [This paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0031-9163(63)90452-9) appears to be the original definition of U-spin.

Comment: no, actually the [Feb 63 PRL] is. http://authors.library.caltech.edu/7723/1/MESprl63.pdf

Answer (score 7):

U-spin is very similar to isospin which interchanges *u* and *d* quarks, except, now, U-spin interchanges *d* and *s* quarks, so, in the [Eightfold-way weight multiplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon#Isospin_and_charge), it transitions to lower right from upper left---unlike for left to right for isospin.

So, *behold!*, in the baryon octet, the $\Sigma^-$ is part of a U-doublet, the $\Sigma^0$ mixing with the $\Lambda^0$ to provide the center of a U-triplet, and the $\Sigma^+$ of a doublet.

In the decuplet, the $\Sigma^{*+}$ is in a doublet, the $\Sigma^{*0}$ a triplet, and the $\Sigma^{*-}$ a quartet. These are exactly the values *u*=1/2 and 3/2 you are puzzled by, above. Two pictures are worth a thousand words.

The underlying reason is the asymmetry of the triangular decuplet weight diagram. The top apex of the increasing-V decuplet triangle is the $\Delta^{++}$, so, as you jack up the *V*-spin, you transition from a U-quartet ultimately to a U-singlet in it.